# Array of Structures in C. not linked list

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am having trouble making an array of structures. I want to store data regarding multiple students and take input using the execution of the program. Then output the memory address of persons name with highest marks.

I tried getting to know the answers on similar issues on site, to no help.

The code I have written is

the struct

```
struct student{
    char name;
    int marks;
};
```

and the function is

```
int num,max = 0,i;
    printf("Number of students?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    struct student* students = (struct student*)malloc (num* (sizeof(struct student)));
    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        printf("Enter Name\n");
        scanf("%c" , &students[x].name);
        printf("Enter Marks\n");
        scanf ("%d" , &students[x].marks);
    }   
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (students[max].marks<students[i].marks)
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The Memory Add for %c is %p\n", students[max].name , &students[max].name );
```

It is a part of menu driven program. It goes into a weird loop after line 5 in function code. And i can't create a doubly linked list for the same.

**Edit 1**

These are the changes i made to struct and func

```
struct student{
    char name[20];
    int marks;
};


void memadd(){
    int num,max = 0,i, mark;

    printf("Number of students?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    struct student* students = (struct student*)malloc (num* (sizeof(struct student)));
    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        printf("Enter Name\n");
        scanf("%s" , &students[x].name);

        printf("Enter Marks\n");
        scanf ("%d" , &mark);
        students[x].marks = mark;
    }   
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (students[max].marks<students[i].marks)
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The Memory Add for %s is %p\n", students[max].name , &students[max].name );
```

It is giving an array at input of the name. "format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has
      type 'char (*)[20]'"

How do I make the format to be char * [20]?

**Edit 2**
The final working code after correcting the char name to being a character array
And issue with scanning of names.

```
struct student{
    char name[20];
    int marks;
};
int num,max = 0,i, mark;

    printf("Number of students?\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    struct student* students = (struct student*)malloc (num* (sizeof(struct student)));
    for (int x = 0; x < num; x++)
    {
        printf("Enter Name\n");
        scanf("%19s" , students[x].name);

        printf("Enter Marks\n");
        scanf ("%d" , &mark);
        students[x].marks = mark;
    }   
    for (i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        if (students[max].marks<students[i].marks)
        {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The Memory Add for %s is %p\n", students[max].name , &students[max].name );
```

However, what if I wish to print the address in Hex numbers? or the one that am getting is hex already.?
Because I got an output of *The Memory Add for XYZ is 0x7fb340c03928*

Comment: Is the first entry in your struct `char name`? That certainly should be an array of chars, e.g. `char name[80]`, which should then be scanned with `%s`, or better yet, `%79s`.

Comment: You must remove the `&`, because the array `name` already points to the address of the first element.

Comment: yeah thanks. It was the only remaining error in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the student name being a char and

```
scanf("%c" , &students[x].name);
```

What happens is, you read in the number of students with

```
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Now you have read `num`, but there is still a newline in the input buffer.
Then you try to read a character with `%c`, but this reads the remaining newline.

When you change the student's name to a character array, e.g.

```
struct student{
    char name[20];
    int marks;
};
```

and read the name with

```
scanf("%19s" , students[x].name);
```

it will skip the remaining whitespace/newline and read the name as it should.